# How to disable/prevent default ipv6 route with systemd-networkd

Tags: ipv6, systemd

I'm using systemd-networkd on my linux router, and this is `ip -6 route` output:

```
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
240e:3b0:3041:4df::/64 dev ppp0 proto ra metric 1024 expires 2591826sec pref medium
240e:3b5:3012:bab1::/64 dev br-lan proto kernel metric 256 expires 3174sec pref medium
unreachable 240e:3b5:3012:bab0::/60 dev lo proto dhcp metric 1024 pref medium
fe80::329c:234f:d1d5:629a dev ppp0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::3826:69ff:fe0e:ff3a dev ppp0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev br-lan proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default dev br-lan proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::3826:69ff:fe0e:ff3a dev ppp0 proto ra metric 1024 expires 1626sec mtu 1492 pref medium
```

The `default dev br-lan proto kernel metric 256 pref medium` make my ipv6 not working. I can run `ip -6 route del default dev br-lan` to delete it, then ipv6 works well.
But I must run this every reboot.

Is there an option to disable this default route?

this is my br-lan config file:

```
[Match]
Name=br-lan

[Network]
Description=The local network
DHCP=no
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
IPv6SendRA=yes
IPv6PrivacyExtensions=no
DHCPv6PrefixDelegation=yes
DHCPPrefixDelegation=yes
DHCPServer=no
MulticastDNS=yes
LLDP=yes
EmitLLDP=yes
IPForward=yes
ConfigureWithoutCarrier=yes
IPv6MTUBytes=1492

[Link]
MTUBytes=9000
ActivationPolicy=always-up

[Address]
Address=10.0.0.1/20
Scope=link

[Address]
Address=fe80::1
Scope=link

[Route]
Scope=link
Metric=8192
IPv6Preference=low
Type=local

[IPv6SendRA]
UplinkInterface=:none
DNS=_link_local

[DHCPPrefixDelegation]
SubnetId=0x1
Announce=yes
UplinkInterface=ppp0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that your configuration deliberately adds the route:

```
[Route]
Scope=link
Metric=8192
IPv6Preference=low
Type=local
```

Without a `Destination=`, this would create a `::/0` route by default.

Otherwise it may be added as a "subnet" route for your `fe80::1` IP address:

```
[Address]
Address=fe80::1
```

As you specified the adderss without a prefix length, some versions of networkd assume a `/0` prefix length (I *think* this was a bug; it should have assumed `/128` instead; but /64 is the proper one in your case).

Change it to `Address=fe80::1/64`.